# in which cases we need to clear the array in bash script

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

In the following example , we set the array variable - *files_in_array* , with all xml files that find command captured under /tmp

note - we use the second "(" ")" to create array

```
files_in_array=( $( find /tmp -type f -name '*.xml' ) )
```

so now we can capture the first/second value .. etc , as the following

```
echo ${files_in_array[0]}

/tmp/demo_values.xml


echo ${files_in_array[1]}

/tmp/prod_values.xml
```

*until now everything is perfect*

but I am not sure if we need to clear the array as

```
 files_in_array=()
```

so , do we must to clear the array before use the array in bash script ?

Comment: You need not to do it.

Comment: in that case - in which case/scenario we need to clear the array ?

Comment: In no case/scenario. Why do you think an array need to be cleared?

Comment: @enodmilvado no cases. For what? You can do smth like that: ```a=123; echo $a; a=456; echo $a```. In output: ```123 456```, variable will be just reassigned.

Comment: That's not a safe way to set the array in the first place; it breaks if any files contain whitespace, and may break if file names contain special glob characters.

Comment: You would need to "clear" the array if you had unknown crap stored in it before you started using it for some new purpose that didn't want the unknown crap.  But you don't need to initialize it before first use. The only arrays that need special initialization are associative arrays, which you'd create using `declare -A`. Check the bash man page for `declare` options. There are a few other things you can do with `declare` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like variables arrays are defined in the shell process environment, unlike variables they can't be exported to be accessed in child processes.

The first command you give

```
files_in_array=( $( find /tmp -type f -name '*.xml' ) )
```

initialises the array if files_in_array contained data, it will be cleared.

As said in comments this is not a safe way to initialise array the way you did because after process expansion `$(..)` the result is split on spaces tabs and newlines and a filename may be split into elemnts, a safe way is to use glob file expansion because it occurs after and is not split.
So just

```
files_in_array=( /tmp/*.xml )
```

to get all sub path

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
files_in_array=( /tmp/**/*.xml )
```

## before bash 4.0

as said in comments globstar was  introduced in bash 4.0, before this another way to do it with find -print0

```
files_in_array=(  )
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
    files_in_array+=( "$file" )
done < <( find /tmp -type f -name '*.xml' -print0 )
```

Comment: just to summary your answer - I need to ad the - shopt -s globstar before the - files_in_array=( $( find /tmp -type f -name '*.xml' ) ) , am I correct ?

Comment: no globstar option is just to use `**` in pattern to match all subfolders like find but in your case it seems it's not needed because you wrote : `/tmp/demo_values.xml`, so just the glob matching is necessary th call to find is useless and unsafe (depending on characters) because of shell splitting output

Comment: I use the find in order to find all *.xml files under /tmp , so if you say that find isn't safe , then how the approach to find all xml files? , I can by ls , but I think both find and ls are give the same results

Comment: ot maybe first to do list=$( find /tmp -type f -name '*.xml' )   , and then files_in_array=( $list )    ??

Comment: just want to add that .xml files under /tmp could be any numbers  , for example 3 or 4 or 6 .xml files ,

Comment: `/tmp/*.xml` expands to all xml files. have you tried the exact command in my answer?

Comment: I get - files_in_array=( /tmp/*.xml )
 echo $files_in_array
/tmp/*.xml
 so this isnt what I want , what we need is all the path of all xml files under /tmp

Comment: your last comment is not consistent with the example in question, updated `globstar` to allow `**` subpath, and `nullglob` so that when there is no match result is empty and not the pattern with `*`

Comment: Worth pointing out that `globstar` is an option that was introduced in bash version 4. There are still systems that ship with bash version 3 (coughMacOS), so a mention of this requirement might be good to see in the answer.

Comment: ny bash version -  bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: now its working - when I set shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
files_in_array=( /tmp/**/*.xml )   , but after I use shop command do we need to return back as before the shopt commands ?

Comment: or in other words what is the opposite for the command - shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob  , ?

Comment: shopt -u globstar; shopt -u nullglob